# xamarin webview html content text color change

Tags: xamarin, webview, textcolor

Its been a while I am searching for the solution.
How to change the text color of the html content to white 
 on webview for xamarin.forms application(shared project) (by default the  text color is black so with transparent background its not visible).I am only looking for Android platform

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to on the Xamarin side regarding Data Your going to display in the Webview, thats Pure Html,css and js....

follow this tutorial to get more understading about it
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/